# Prevent hashmap key entries added more than once?

Tags: java, hashmap, bukkit

I am creating a minigame engine for Minecraft with Bukkit, but it seems like there is a problem with adding a player to the game. After a player is being successfully added, he has the ability to join again, as a result, participating more than once.

It is really odd, because in my if-statement I do check if the HashMap with the participants contains the player key. If it does, it should not allow him to join the game again.

Here is my method.

```
public void addPlayer(Client client) {

    // Checks if the game is waiting, and the slots are sufficient.

    if (game.isWaiting() && !game.isFull() && !game.getClients().containsKey(client)) {

        Random random = new Random();

        int teamChance = random.nextInt(game.getTeams().size());

        // Adding the player to the match and assigning the default kit.

        game.getClients().put(client, game.getDefaultKit());

        // Adding the player to a team.

        game.getTeams().get(teamChance).add(client);

        // Checking if the slots are now maximum, prepare the game.

        if (game.isFull()) {
            prepareGame();
        }

        // If the player was added.

        if (game.getClients().containsKey(client))
        {
            Main.log("Added " + client.getName() + " (" + game.getCurrentSlots() + "/" + game.getSlots() + ")" + " to " + game.getType().getName() + " (" + game.getWorld().getName() + ").", Level.INFO);

            game.broadcast("Join", client.getName() + " (" + game.getCurrentSlots() + "/" + game.getSlots() + ")");

            client.getPlayer().teleport(game.getWorld().getSpawnLocation());

            client.reset();

            // Adding lobby items to the player's inventory.

            new LobbyManager(game);
        }
    }
```

From the `Game` class.

```
private HashMap<Client, Kit> clients;

// ...

public HashMap<Client, Kit> getClients() {
    return this.clients;
}
```

How do I modify this method in order to prevent a player being added to the game more than once?

Your help is much appreciated.

---

Client: http://pastebin.com/Fmgc0T3C

Comment: Have you implemented `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `Client` class?

Comment: Hmm, since I am a fairly new to Java, it seems like the player is being added, but twice because Client works like a wrapper class for the Player (in order to implement my own methods). No, I haven't.

Comment: are you working with threads?

Comment: Yes, because since I am working with Bukkit, there are more 'Plugins' loaded to the server. But I am using only my own.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if this was a thread race issue. My money is on equals and hashcode, 100%.

Comment: Working on it, however I do not implement any interfaces, because I am only storing a Player from the constructor to a variable, and then wrapping it with other methods. So there must be the problem (?).

http://pastebin.com/Fmgc0T3C - Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible that two threads are adding the same client, you should [lock](http://tutorialsjenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html) the operations where you add them to the games! When you are creating a new client object every time a player wants to join, you have to override [`equals()` and `hashCode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java), because `conainsKey` will return false when you are comparing the same client in different client objects.